# FF/Latch has a constand value of 0 because of parameter

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I am building an UART RX and I want to make it synthesis-time configurable wether or not a parity bit is received:

```
module uart_rx # (
    parameter EXPECT_PARITY_BIT = 0,
    parameter CLK_PER_BAUD = 434,
    parameter CLK_PER_BAUD_WIDTH = 9
) (
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input uart_rx,
    output reg data_ready,
    output reg parity_bit = 1'H0,
    output [7:0] data
);
```

If EXPECT_PARITY_BIT is zero, the following happens in the FSM:

```
receiveData:
    if (current_rx_bit == 8) begin
        if (EXPECT_PARITY_BIT == 1)
            nextState = receiveParity;
        else
            nextState = receiveStop;
    end
```

The variable parity_bit is set as follows:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst == 1)
        parity_bit <= 1'H0;
    else if (receive_parity == 1 && mtimer_done == 1)
        parity_bit <= uart_rx;
end
```

Receive_parity is only high in state receiveParity, meaning that parity_bit will be zero if unused. This leads to a warning by webpack ISE:

```
Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <parity_bit> has a constant value of 0 in block <uart_rx>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

And I want to fix this warning. How should I program my UART RX such that receiving parity is optional and no warnings appear during synthesis?

Comment: I have given up on suppressing warnings  a long time ago. In my C or C++ code I still do this, in HDL I found it impossible. Certainly with the Xilinx tools.

Answer (score 0):

Since it a non-runtime evaluation you can use a generate block (assuming your toolset is Verilog-2001 compliment).

Example (not tested):

```
generate
  if (EXPECT_PARITY_BIT == 1) begin : g_parity
    always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (rst == 1)
        parity_bit <= 1'H0;
      else if (receive_parity == 1 && mtimer_done == 1)
        parity_bit <= uart_rx;
    end
  end
  else begin : g_no_parity
    initial parity_bit = 1'b0;
  end
endgenerate
```

Warns are something to be reviewed, but they don’t always need to be resolved. I prefer resolving warnings when possible to increase the chances of seeing real issues. But there are cases where it is not worth the effort to resolve.